# Which application is executed first?

Tags: haskell

I have following instance of Traversable:

```
  instance Traversable (Three' a) where
    traverse f (Three' x y z) = Three' x <$> f y <*> f z
```

the infix operator `<$>` and `<*>` has the same precedence and namely 4.

```
*ExercisesTraversable> :i <$>
(<$>) :: Functor f => (a -> b) -> f a -> f b
    -- Defined in ‘Data.Functor’
infixl 4 <$>


*ExercisesTraversable> :i <*>
class Functor f => Applicative (f :: * -> *) where
  ...
  (<*>) :: f (a -> b) -> f a -> f b
  ...
    -- Defined in ‘GHC.Base’
infixl 4 <*>
```

Which one is going to executed first?

Comment: `f <$> x <*> y = (<*>) ((<$>) f x) y)`. To see why, read the [report](https://www.haskell.org/onlinereport/haskell2010/haskellch10.html#x17-18100010.6).

Comment: Order of execution is immaterial in a pure language: any order will give the same result. You are probably wondering about operator precedence. Note that evaluation order and precedence are distinct notions.

Comment: @chi Minor quibble: any evaluation order *that terminates* will get the same result. But it's possible (common, even -- basically any time recursion appears) for one order to loop forever while another order gets an answer. Idiomatic Haskell programs (and, therefore, the programmers writing those programs) frequently rely on lazy evaluation order to terminate.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

They don't just have precedence 4, they also have left-associativity. This is the `l` in `infixl`; one can also choose `infixr` for right-associativity, and `infix` for "throw an error if you need to know what the associativity should be". Thus

```
Three' x <$> f y <*> f z
```

is parsed as:

```
(Three' x <$> f y) <*> f z
```

As for which is *executed* first, that can't be answered without seeing the implementation of `(<*>)` that you want to ask about; `Three' x <$> f y` will be evaluated just far enough for `(<*>)` to make progress, as usual, so if `(<*>)` can make progress without evaluating the `(<$>)` call first, it will.